# How can I run many CAAnimations at once without a slowdown?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

If I want to have 20 objects all running their own animation on the screen at once, is there any way to go about doing that without an obvious slowdown?

My example here is the main screen, in edit mode.  Every icon on the screen is shaking slightly, but there's no noticeable slowdown.  When I tried something similar, the animation slows to a crawl at maybe 5 FPS.

Comment: Which animation methods are you using?

Comment: Well, in the example I gave above, I am just using keyframe animations to animate the transform property with random rotation (between -.1 and .1) and a random translation (between -5 and 5 px in each direction) with four steps on each view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference could be compositing, transparency is very expensive to calculate and doing much overlapping stuff can quickly bog things down.

You may be better off moving to OpenGL (or a library like Cocos2D) if you are doing complex sprite animation.  You can use OpenGL mixed with normal views...

Comment: Do you think that the home screen uses OpenGL to do its display?